# Invalid expression term 'string' C#

Tags: c#, string

I have this code for reading the next line in a text file, but it gives me the error Invalif expression term 'string'.

Here's my code:

```
             private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {

            String text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;


            List<string> filecontents = File.ReadAllLines(filename).ToList < string();
            for (int i = 0; i < filecontents.Count; i++)
            {
                if (filecontents[i].Contains(text))
                {
                    string error = filecontents[i + 1];
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: It's `ToList < string();` that's causing the problem. I don't know what syntax you're aiming for there, but it should just be `ToList();`

Comment: Yeah, the error tells you what the problem is. It even tells/indicates the location of the error. Just move your eyes towards the location the error points at... ;-)

Comment: Ok Thank you very much ! Appriciate it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line generates the error:

```
List<string> filecontents = File.ReadAllLines(filename).ToList < string();
```

I guess you wanted to write this:

```
List<string> filecontents = File.ReadAllLines(filename).ToList<string>();
```

This is another way to write it:

```
List<string> filecontents = new List<string>( File.ReadAllLines(filename) );
for (int i = 0; i < filecontents.Count; i++)
{
    if (filecontents[i].Contains(text))
    {
        string error = filecontents[i + 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: *but File.ReadAllLines returns string[] in which you cannot use ToList method.* Yes, it can. `ToList` operates on `IEnumerable<T>`, which arrays implement. The correct way to write it would be `List<string> filecontents = File.ReadAllLines(filename).ToList();`. Specifying a type is unnecessary.

Comment: You are right. I edited and corrected it. You have to include System.Linq and then you can use ToList method to string[].

Comment: Although you don't need the type argument, as it's the one that would be inferred anyway. While it's *valid* to use `ToList<string>()` it's unconventional.